# Add text to an equirectangular photo

Tags: cycles-render-engine, text-object

I've got an [equirectangular](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equirectangular_projection) photo and I want to add a simple text to the scene. Is it possible to do that easily with Blender Cycles or some other technique?

Comment: If you know what camera and lens the picture was taken with it will be a lot easier.

Comment: In the past I have just projected an equirectangular image into the world as a texture then placed text in front of that.

Comment: It's a photo sphere (stitched images) from Google Camera app. The photo was captured using Nexus 6P device if that matters. I just want to add some text visible on the bottom of the image.

Comment: What is not clear for me: do you want to see a scene in Blender with this image and a text, OR, do you want to save the photo back to disk, with the text and the same format?

Comment: I want to save it back to a disk (preferably without quality loss) so I can view it later in my VR

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First setup your equirectangular image as an environment texture to the world surface :

- Go to the world panel, in the surface part: choose 'environment texture', then your image and select 'equirectangular'.

(below, the world panel setting on the right, the node equivalent on bottom and the view rendered on top with default cube in place)

[image]

- Add a camera, set it to 'panoramic' in its property panel, then choose 'equirectangular'. This camera will be used to render the scene, so you can here choose its orientation in order to have the same centered image as your original (as you need).

[image]

- Add a text... somewhere... depending on where you want it to be.

To adjust its position, go in camera view <kbd>Numpad0</kbd> in rendered mode, select your text, and move/rotate/scale it as needed

[image]

- Now we need to render the image :

Go to the render panel, choose the size you need and the format you want, and click on 'render' :

[image]

- Save your image <kbd>F3</kbd> and in the options which are at the bottom left, choose the export format you want :

[image]

- You are done. To test the result, simply set this new image as environment texture (as we did for the original image at the begining)

Comment: Perfect, I struggled at the beginning because I didn't set the correct render engine. So remember guys to set the engine to "Cycles Render". Thank you!